# Несколько массивов в цикле for

Tags: java

Осваиваю массивы и циклы, и столкнулся с проблемой. Есть 2 массива, с заданными рандомными параметрами. И при цикле из каждого элемента массива al[] должен вычитаться параметр каждого элемента массива en[].atk. + параметр al[].res. Цикл работает, но только в 1 этап, после чего выдает ошибку Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at Main.main(Main.java:22). Я понимаю что я сделал не правильное обращение ко 2 массиву, но я не могу понять как именно правильно к нему обратиться.

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Ally[] al = new Ally[3];
    al[0] = new Ally("Hero One");
    al[1] = new Ally("Hero Two");
    al[2] = new Ally("Hero Three");
    Enemy[] en = new Enemy[3];
    en[0] = new Enemy("Enemy One");
    en[1] = new Enemy("Enemy Two");
    en[2] = new Enemy("Enemy Three");
    System.out.println("Hero check \n");
    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++){
      System.out.println(al[i].name+ " HP = "+ al[i].hp+" Attack = "+al[i].atk+" Resist = "+al[i].res);
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Enemy check \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      System.out.println(en[i].name+ " HP = "+en[i].hp+ " Attack = "+en[i].atk+ " Resist = "+en[i].res);
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Battle begin \n");
    for (int j = 0; j < al[j].hp; j++){
        al[j].hp = al[j].hp - en[j].atk + al[j].res;
        System.out.println(al[j].name+ " HP = "+ al[j].hp+" Attack = "+al[j].atk+" Resist = "+al[j].res);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Что происходит в этой строчке? ` for (int j = 0; j < al[j].hp; j++)`

Comment: По моей логике, он обращается к "j" элементу массива, переменной hp, которая к примеру равна 40, и сравнивает ее с условием "Меньше ли она 0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом цикле

```
for (int j = 0; j < al[j].hp; j++){
         al[j].hp = al[j].hp - en[j].atk + al[j].res;
        System.out.println(al[j].name+ " HP = "+ al[j].hp+"   Attack = "+al[j].atk+" Resist = "+al[j].res);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
```

al[j] пытается обратиться к ячейке **al[al[j].hp]**, и, что-то мне подсказывает, что значение **al[al[j].hp]** выходит далеко за рамки значений 0...3. - т.е **40**. Вот тут Вы и схватываете ошибку "выход за рамки массива".

Поменяйте на

```
 for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
```

А еще лучше на

```
 for (int j = 0; j < al.length; j++)
```

Как-бы других рамок быть не может в Вашем случае

Предлагаю следуещее решение, к Вашему коментарию (даю псевдокод, т.к. С телефона)

1. Создаем флаг

   ```
    boolean b = false;
   ```
2. Применяем в цикле **while**

   ```
    while(!b){
          //логика цикла....
         if (елемент1 < 0)&(елемент2 <0) { 
         b = true;
      }
   ```

   }

Comment: Спасибо! Да, это работает. Но может быть направите в нужное русло. Необходимо чтобы цикл завершался тогда, когда переменная hp каждого элемента массива al будет меньше чем 0. Возможно я изначально обратился с неправильным вопросом. Спасибо!

Comment: Если помогло, ставте отметку "решено". Это лучшая благодарность, да и Вам добавит пару балов к рейтингу

Comment: Помогло! Большое Вам спасибо! Закрываю тему.

Comment: Вы не закрывайте)..Поставьте галочку в верху моего ответа